# Xcode 4: Temporarily removing lines of code you might want to put back

Tags: xcode4

I am new to programming with no formal programming training, so please excuse this newbie question.  I can't seem to find a definitive answer on it, and need to be sure.

Here's the scenario: sometimes I need to try different lines of code to see if they work, but still want to keep the original lines in there in case the new lines don't work (or for future reference).  I thought by putting // in front of the line I want to "comment out" would mean the line of code would be ignored when compiling the program, but my app crashed and pointed to a line I thought was commented out.  I am using Xcode 4.

Is there another symbol I should be using to comment out lines or blocks of code? For example, will /* at the beginning and */ at the end accomplish this?

Comment: You really don't want to keep the code in there "for future reference". Commented-out code is not tested or maintained, so it soon begins to rot. If you try to add it back sometimes later, it's not going to work anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Bo.  I'll make sure I get rid of all my "commented out" code in the final.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For "commenting out" big blocks of code, I do conditionals like:

```
#if I_AM_TESTING_SO_DONT_COMPILE_THIS
...
...
...
...
#endif // I_AM_TESTING_SO_DONT_COMPILE_THIS
```

And yes, the traditional C-style `/*` and `*/` also work to "comment out" blocks of code.

The reason your compile crashed with `//` is because while a single line gets commented out, you might have had some extra code on a second line.

Such as:

```
//NSString * someContentFromSomewhere = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
    [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.stackoverflow.com"]];
```

The first line is commented out.  The second line is a syntax error.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I would imagine you would put this at the beginning of the code you don't want to compile.  Is there something at the end where you tell it to stop?

Comment: yes... an `#endif` balances out the `#if` conditional part.  Your code goes where the ellipses (dots) are.  :-)

Comment: Thank you again.  I wish I could rate your answer but I don't have enough points yet!  I certainly will mark it correct.

Comment: Thanks for already knowing how StackOverflow works.  You'd be surprised how many people ask questions but never say "thanks" by accepting or voting helpful answers up.

Answer (score 2):

Also, make sure you do a clean build. It's possible that sometimes old object files are used and even though you commented out a line in the IDE, it may not have build with that updated file.

Comment: Yes, I already found out about that.  Everytime I do a build I clean it, save it, then run it.  It might be overkill but I want to be sure that if I get an error it's really an error for the change I made.

Comment: I agree. I've been burned by various build systems too many times to not do a clean build :).

Comment: I also should add (for any newbies reading this) I delete the app from my device as well.  I've found especially working with core data you need to do that.